# Which file format should I use as an alternative to my current Excel worksheet?

Tags: .net, data, strings, storage, excel

My .NET application does its work and then creates a report (an Excel worksheet). That report contains thousands of short text strings [KEY - VALUE]. So Excel worksheets suites very well, one column holds the keys and another holds the values. It's easy to examine this reports.

But because of performance issues now, I'm trying to find another file format to create reports in .NET in a way that's easy to manually examine, like a table or plain text.

What kind of file format would you recommend?

Comment: "*But because of performance issues*" - are you only writing the data, or at what point do you have those issues exactly? Within your program while writing (and how do you do that right now)? Within Excel (version?) while reading the data?

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490

Comment: @JensG, My application is only writing huge massives of data into Excel 2013 worksheet. It takes too much time. And if there're too many values needed to be written to the report application just freezes without exception during writing data to report. I have read somewhere that it is NET-COM operationing issues.

Comment: Ah, you are using COM, I nearly guessed it from your question but was not sure. Complicated and slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about [Comma-separated values(CSV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)?

- simple text-based format
- can be edited via Text editor
- Excel and a lot of other tools are able to read and/or write it

You just need to be aware of the fact, that not all CSV is CSV. There are a lot of flavours out there with different separators.

Comment: looks like CSV is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!